# Auto check boxes by checking against the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function which builds out a list of categories from the categories table from my database:

What I am trying to achieve is for it to auto tick the checkboxes if that post belong to that category when I come to edit it. I have a join table which takes the id of the post and the id of the category which then makes the association. I am not sure where to start? I am fairly new to php but here is my attempt:

```
<?php

function build_cat_checkboxes(){

    global $dbc;
    global $id;

    $q1 = "SELECT cat_id FROM doc_cat_join WHERE doc_id = '$id'";
    $r1 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q1);
    var_dump($r1);    

    $q = "SELECT * FROM cats";
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q); //Run the query.   

    $currentDoc = $id;    

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    $checked = (($row['cat_id'] == $currentDoc) ? 'checked' : '');    

    echo '<ul>
          <li><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '"  checked="'.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
          </ul>';
    }    
}   

?>
```

So now I am actually getting back the results I expected from my join table by checking the doc_id and also the cat_id and it counts the rows, bow I am a little stuck on the looping of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop, check the current 'cat_id' against whatever static value you have, and if they match, set $checked to 'checked'.

```
$currentCat = '123';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) {

    $checked = (($row['cat_id'] == $currentCat) ? 'checked' : '');

    echo '<ul>
          <li><label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cat_id[]" value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '"  checked="'.$checked.'"> ' . $row["cat_name"] . '</label></li>
          </ul>';
}
```

Comment: Ok so I see wht your doing here - instead o the $currentCat I am actually on a page where I am editing my post and the categories are checkboxes

Comment: Hm ok so they are now checked but if I edit the doc and take it away from a category it still shows as ticked?

Comment: Checkbox values only get submitted IF THEY ARE CHECKED.  So, on update, first delete all checkbox values, then insert the ones submitted in the form.

Comment: that is true - It is working as it did before so if I check them it chucks them into the join table and also if I take them away they delete from the join table but even if the rows exist or not they still automatically tick - should it be taking a look at the join table?

Comment: You may need 2 queries.  One from the 'cats' table to get the Category details (will return 1 row), and then 1 from the 'doc_cat_join' table (that will return multiple rows).

Comment: Hm, how would I approach that? I have tried to query both tables but it dosnt make a difference